# C structures, memory alloc and structures

Tags: c, malloc, structure

So, the task is to read file and push data to structure. the data file is:

```
babe 12 red 12
deas 12 blue 12
dsa 12 red 512
bxvx 15 blue 52
reed 18 black 15
```

while code is something like that

```
struct shoes {
    char name[8];
    int size;
    char color[8];
    int price;       
};
//open file
shoes *item=(struct shoes*)malloc(sizeof(struct shoes));
for (i=0; !feof(file); i++) {
    item=(struct shoes*)realloc(item,sizeof(struct shoes)+i*sizeof(struct shoes));
    fscanf(file,"%s %i %s %i\n",(item+i)->name,(item+i)->size,(item+i)->color,(item+i)->price);
}
```

but the program crashes every time.
dbg says: No symbol "item" in current context.
where is error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code has some bugs:
1) You need a typedef for shoes unless you're compiling with a C++ compiler ... but then you should have tagged this C++.
2) feof doesn't return false until an attempt has actually been made to read beyond the end of file, so your code makes the array of shoes 1 too large.
3) You're passing ints to fscanf instead their addresses.

If compiling as C code, not C++ code, the casts on malloc and realloc aren't necessary and are advised against. And there are other stylistic issues that make you code harder to comprehend than it could be. Try this:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[8];
    int size;
    char color[8];
    int price;       
} Shoe;

// [open file]

Shoe* shoes = NULL; // list of Shoes
Shoe shoe; // temp for reading

for (i = 0; fscanf(file,"%s %i %s %i\n", shoe.name, &shoe.size, shoe.color, &shoe.price) == 4; i++)
{
    shoes = realloc(shoes, (i+1) * sizeof *shoes);
    if (!shoes) ReportOutOfMemoryAndDie();
    shoes[i] = shoe;
}
```

Comment: yeah, i've used a gcc, so it works fine. i'll follow better the specifications in future)

Comment: @wingsofovnia I had an important typo which I've fixed ... `shoes[i] = shoe`, not `shoes`.

Comment: Why read into a temporary at all, instead of directly in place?

Comment: @NikBougalis See my item #2 ... you don't know whether there's another item in the file until you try to read it. An alternative approach is to extend the list before reading, read into the next element, and then realloc down to the actual size after EOF. That approach works well with growing the list by more than one element ... e.g., doubling the size when it's full -- necessary for performance for large lists. But the implementation I gave is simple, understandable, and accurate.

Comment: Valid point. I should have noticed that in my answer. THanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are not passing *pointers* to the integers you want to read using `fscanf`, you are passing the integers themselves.

`fscanf` treats them as pointers. And where do they point? Who knows - the integers were uninitialized, so they could point *ANYWHERE*. Therefore, *CRASH*.

Fix thusly:

```
fscanf(file,"%s %i %s %i\n",
    (item+i)->name,
    &((item+i)->size),
    (item+i)->color,
    &((item+i)->price));
```

Note that you don't need the same for `name` and `color` because arrays degenerate to pointers, so you're passing the right thing already.

And please, consider ditching the `item+i` notation; `item[i]` is *so* much clearer and easier to understand when casually reading the code:

```
fscanf("%s %i %s %i\n", 
    item[i].name, 
    &item[i].size, 
    item[i].color,
    &item[i].price);
```

Comment: thank you, everything seems work well. but have some questions: 1) why (item+i)->size is't a pointer? while (item+i)->name is a pointer? 2) is ptr+i equal ptr[i],right?

Comment: I explained to you why: `name` is an array and arrays will degenerate into pointers; so when you try to pass `(item+i)->name` you are passing a pointer to the first element of the array. `size` on the other hand isn't an array, it's an integer. You need to explicitly get a *pointer* to it to give to `fscanf`, which is why the `&` (the "address-of" operator) is necessary. And yes, `ptr+i` is the same as `ptr[i]`, but the subscript syntax is a bit clearer and avoids the need for parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the *debugger* says that? I'm surprised it even compiled...

You wanted:

```
struct shoes *item
```

If you don't proved a typedef of your structure, you have to explicitly say "struct" every time you reference it.

Second note:

```
item=(struct shoes*)realloc(item...
```

Don't assign the same pointer from [`realloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) that you pass into it. If the reallocation fails it will return NULL and that could be killing you. You should make sure you're checking the results of both the initial `malloc()` and the `realloc()`

Third point:

You need to be passing the *address* of the int's to the fscanf().

```
fscanf(file,"%s %i %s %i\n",(item+i)->name,&((item+i)->size),(item+i)->color,&((item+i)->price));
```

Comment: anyway, crash is still here(

Comment: @wingsofovnia - OK, first check my updated, check your returns and see if the allocations are always successful. Second what is the *exact* error that you get, and what line does it occur at?

Comment: crash happens in fscanf line

Comment: His allocations (weird as they are) are correct and almost certainly succeed. His problem is passing uninitialized integers in the place of pointers.

Comment: @wingsofovnia - that's ok, I realized where the issue was. Your fscanf() call is passing the `int`s incorrectly.

Comment: @NikBougalis - Yup, just saw that myself too

Comment: "Don't assign the same pointer from realloc() that you pass into it" -- The only reason to avoid that is if you're a purist who frees the old memory if realloc fails rather than just exiting ... but there's really no point to it; if you ran out of memory, your program is unlikely to be able to recover.

Comment: "I'm surprised it even compiled..." -- It's legal C++, but not C.

Comment: @JimBalter - The question is tagged C, not C++

Comment: Yes, duh -- see my answer. But the OP apparently used a C++ compiler, which is why it compiled. Still surprised?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code:

1st. The struct:

you could define your struct in two ways,
the way you did:

```
struct shoe{    
 char name[8];
 int size;
 char color[8];
 int price;  
};
```

and in this case you should refer to a pointer to it as:

```
struct shoe *item;
```

the other (perhaps more convenient?) way using a typedef along with the defenition:

```
typedef struct {    
 char name[8];
 int size;
 char color[8];
 int price;  
} shoe;
```

and in this case you should refer to a pointer to it as:

```
shoe *item;
```

Therefore the code you posted isn't supposed to compile.

2nd one:

fscanf should be given pointers to integers/chars in the case you showed.
You've correctly passed the char pointer(since you passed the name of a char array which is actually a char pointer to the first element), but you have passed some integers and fscanf needs pointer to integers it is supposed to fill, so your code should be:

```
fscanf(file,"%s %i %s %i\n",(item+i)->name,&((item+i)->size),(item+i)->color,&((item+i)->price));
```